# Jetbrains Webstorm 9.0.3 big blinking cursor and not able to type ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ide, webstorm, ubuntu-14.10

I have installed a trial copy of Jetbrains Webstorm 9.0.3 in Ubuntu 14.10, I am having a peculiar problem of not able to edit the created files, and the text cursor (blinking cursor) also appears very **BIG**.

[image: Cursor]

Occasionally, a configuration error growl message appears on top right, indicating some problem with the *workspace.xml* file.

Does this have anything to set with the file permissions?.

I am new to this IDE, any help is appreciated.

Comment: does it happen with all files, or some specific ones only? I'd suggest creating a support ticket, attaching your idea.log

Comment: All files, but only using Dracula theme.

Comment: please attach idea.log to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15820

Comment: @lena Posted in Youtrack, please check.